# How to change RenderOption of RibbonButton SmallImageSource

Tags: wpf, image, ribbon-control

I am using `Ribbon` from RibbonControlsLibrary.

The question is how can change the `RenderOption` of `SmallImageSource` for all `RibbonButtons` without defining a `ControlTemplate` from the base?

Comment: I set this in 'ControlSizeDefinition' property of the `RibbonButton` but the `renderOption` of the `smallImageSourse` not changed !?